# android licensing: when generate new key pair

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am reading Android Application Licensing. It uses a key pair to check license. The document also says that:

> Note that if you decide to generate a new licensing key pair for your account for some reason, you need to notify all users of test accounts. For testers, you can embed the new key in the application package and distribute it to users. For developers, you will need to distribute the new key to them directly.

I think this is related to this server response LICENSED_OLD_KEY: "The application is licensed to the user, but there is an updated application version available that is signed with a different key. "

I understand this concept. However, what I am unclear about is when you would need to generate a new licensing key pair. Do we need to generate a new key pair whenever we submit an update? My guess is no. When do we need to generate a new key?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to generate a new key every time you release an update.  You would only need to generate a new key if your existing key was compromised for some reason (e.g. stolen).